# Is there a way to merge point clouds attributes in python?

Tags: python, point-clouds, las

I have two point clouds (.las file). The coordinates of points (x, y,z) are the same in both the data, but one dataset has intensity attribute, while the other one has classification attribute only. I would like to merge these information, and obtain a point cloud with x,y,z, intensity and classification attributes.
I tried converting las file in arrays, but then it take too much time to search for the same point in thee two arrays and append the attributes.

How can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same exact point-cloud, then shouldn't the order be the same?
If the order is the same then you can just do something like:

```
new_pc = np.column_stack([point_cloud1, point_cloud2[:, classification_index])
```

If they are not in the exact same order initially, then just sort both of them out by the x,y,z first. If it is the same point-cloud they will be sorted exactly the same.

Comment: Actually in one of the point cloud, some points are missing, so this solution is not suitable in my case

Comment: Try using pandas merge or something similar.  Check this tutorial for example https://realpython.com/pandas-merge-join-and-concat/